# Select a specific col & row by Datetime with format '4/1/2019 7:57'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have file csv 50 col and 1000 rows, 
I want to select some needed col with a specific date & time. The date & time format in file as shown below.

```
        data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', low_memory=False)        
        columns = [0]
        rows = [0,1,2]
        coal_flow = data.iloc[1, '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27'] 
        air_flow = data.iloc[8, '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27']
        outlet_temp = data.iloc[15, '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27']
        inlet_temp = data.iloc[22, '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27']
        bowl_dp = data.iloc[29, '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27']
        motor_current = data.iloc[36, '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27']
        vibration = data.iloc[43, '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27']
        to_drop = [str]
        data.drop(columns, axis = 1, inplace = True) #drop the two first columns that no need to the code
        data.drop(rows,  axis = 0, inplace = True) #drop the two first rwos that no need to the code
        data = data[~data[:].isin(to_drop)]#drop the specific string or an object type string
        data.dropna(inplace = True)#drop any null value 
        data.to_csv('summary.csv', index = False, header = False)#add the result into csv file
```

Any Idea ?
May convert the format of the datetime

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need `loc` for select by labels, not by positions:

```
coal_flow = data.loc[1, '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27']
```

And also if not default index values select it by position:

```
coal_flow = data.loc[data.index[1], '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27']
```

Comment: got error ` ----> 6 coal_flow = data.loc[1, '4/1/2019 7:57' : '4/1/2019 12:27']`  `ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing` `KeyError: '4/1/2019 7:57'`

Comment: @AbuOmair - What is `print (data.columns)` ?

Comment: its date and time in one cell in the first column **BUT** it show me the first row when I run `print (data.columns) `

Comment: @AbuOmair - Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.